# How to build ionic1- project in ionic3 environment?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

My boss gave me an ionic1 project, but my computer is the ionic3 environment. How can I package the project.

```
'python' : "v-2.7"
'node'   : "v-8.9"
'cordova': 'v-7.1'
'ionic'  : "v-3.18"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just use this command

```
ionic start <YOUR APP NAME> --type=ionic1
```

hope this works for you

Comment: thank you.Is this command for new projects? But the boss has given me a code for the project that's online. Let me build it

Comment: Yes this command is for new project creation, you also copy your code to it

Answer (score 1):

you can create new project from template also

```
 ionic start [<project_name>] [<template>] --type=ionic1
```

example

```
ionic start myApp tabs --type=ionic1
```

for more info: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for building Ionic version 1 app in Ionic 3 environment

For sidemenu:   `ionic start yourappname sidemenu --type ionic1`

For tabs:      `ionic start yourappname tabs --type ionic1`